# SPARQL query that returns Wikidpedia labels from Wikidata itemLabel

Tags: sparql, wikidata, wikidata-query-service

I am new to SPARQL,
Is it possible to write a query that returns Wikipedia box information for a corresponding item label from the Wikipedia box for the Arabic Language that appears at the bottom of the Wikidata item page?

see the picture:

[image: Wikipedia box]

**Instead of the Wikipedia URL in the following Query, I need to return the Wikipedia Label, in our case (الرامة (جنين))**

[Try Query on Wikidata Query Service](https://query.wikidata.org/#%0A%0ASELECT%20DISTINCT%20%3Farticle%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription%20%3Fentity_type%20%3Fmain_category%20%28GROUP_CONCAT%28DISTINCT%28%3FaltLabel%29%3B%20separator%20%3D%20%22%2C%20%22%29%20AS%20%3FaltLabel_list%29%20WHERE%20%7B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20%3Flabel%20%22%D8%A7%D9%84%D8%B1%D8%A7%D9%85%D8%A9%22%40ar.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20%3Fentity_type%20.%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20MINUS%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP31%20wd%3AQ4167410%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%7B%20%20%20%20%3Fitem%20wdt%3AP910%20%3Fmain_category%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%3Farticle%20schema%3Aabout%20%3Fitem%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20schema%3AisPartOf%20%3Chttps%3A%2F%2Far.wikipedia.org%2F%3E%3B%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20OPTIONAL%20%7B%20%3Fitem%20skos%3AaltLabel%20%3FaltLabel%20.%20FILTER%20%28lang%28%3FaltLabel%29%20%3D%20%22ar%22%29%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20SERVICE%20wikibase%3Alabel%20%7B%20bd%3AserviceParam%20wikibase%3Alanguage%20%22ar%22%20.%7D%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%7D%0A%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20%20GROUP%20BY%20%3Farticle%20%3Fitem%20%3FitemLabel%20%3FitemDescription%20%3Fentity_type%20%3Fmain_category%0A%0A)

```
SELECT DISTINCT ?article ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription ?entity_type ?main_category (GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(?altLabel); separator = ", ") AS ?altLabel_list) WHERE {
                            ?item ?label "الرامة"@ar.
                            ?item wdt:P31 ?entity_type .
                            MINUS { ?item wdt:P31 wd:Q4167410}
                            OPTIONAL{    ?item wdt:P910 ?main_category}
                            ?article schema:about ?item;
                            schema:isPartOf <https://ar.wikipedia.org/>;
                            OPTIONAL { ?item skos:altLabel ?altLabel . FILTER (lang(?altLabel) = "ar") }
                            SERVICE wikibase:label { bd:serviceParam wikibase:language "ar" .} 
                        
                                                        }
                            GROUP BY ?article ?item ?itemLabel ?itemDescription ?entity_type ?main_category
```

Comment: not sure what you mean, from Wikidata to Wikipedia article or vice versa? Here is from Wikidata to Wikipedia:`SELECT ?article WHERE {

    
    ?article schema:about wd:Q12187640 .
    ?article schema:isPartOf <https://ar.wikipedia.org/>.

  
}`

Comment: This is very helpful, but instead of Wikipedia URL returned, can we return the Arabic label i.e (الرامة(جنين)) from the Wikipedia box as a result of the query?

Comment: Like this? `SELECT ?article ?wikipediaLabel WHERE {           ?article schema:about wd:Q12187640 .     ?article schema:isPartOf <https://ar.wikipedia.org/>; schema:name ?wikipediaLabel  }`

Comment: Also, what does the query in your edited question do now? If this is the answer, you should provide it as an answer. If not, please give context

Comment: it is not the answer, I need some modification to return the label rather than the URL , and this is clear in body of the question.

Comment: @UninformedUser you saved my life man, thank you very much, how can I mark your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is the answer by the  UninformedUser

```
>      SELECT ?article ?wikipediaLabel WHERE 
>         {           ?article schema:about wd:Q12187640 .     ?article schema:isPartOf <https://ar.wikipedia.org/>; schema:name
> ?wikipediaLabel  }
```